# Android: Display a message during a call

Tags: java, android, notifications

I have a program that makes a phone call when a user clicks on a button. The user will need to provide some information very fast to the person who answers the call(ie GPS coordinates). The problem that I am having is that, once the user clicks on the call button, they cant go back to my application.

I want to know if it possible to bring my application to the front (without hanging up the call) or to display a message until the user clicks the ok button... or something like that. I tried toast notification but they disappear and I want them to stay until the user decides to close it.

Comment: "The problem that I am having is that, once the user clicks on the call button, they cant go back to my application" -- sure they can. They can go back to your application the same way they can go back to any application, via the recent tasks list or launching an activity of yours from the home screen launcher.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [this](http://stackoverflow.com/q/5427017/1101070)?

Comment: @CommonsWare Maybe I did not explained well. In my old cell phone I pressed the back button and my activity was brought to the front, after doing some testing with another cell phone I noticed that pressing the back button does not bring my app to the front. I want a fast way of bringing my activity to the front (not the standard/long way)

Comment: @Marvin I read that thread but that is not what I am looking for. I start the call with my activity and want to have the information provided by my app visible during the call

Answer (score 0):

look up startActivityForResult() and see if you can hook into the calling code.