# On Incoming Call Interesting behavior on Galaxy s2 and Galaxy note

Tags: android, android-intent

I have developed an application that receive PHONE_STATE intent and starting an activity only when state is RINGING. (as described here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/5491773/1027400)

The activity I start is a dialog activity at top position which mean that the background is transparent, I also set it to be untouchable so all touches events will go back to the system ANSWER activity.

the bottom part of the system ANSWER activity is hidden on S2 and note. On other phones it is working fine.

Any clue would be appreciated! Thanks.