# Not Showing a activity on OnReceveive Broadcast when incomming call

Tags: android, broadcastreceiver

I'm trying to make an app that when you receive an incoming call to launch an activity showing the calling number.

My problem is that the activity is not shown until the call is finished.

I put a log in the application and I see that when I get the call activity is launched, and I've put the log in the Create method of the activity, but this is not shown until the call has been hung.

I pass the source code of the activity and the broadcast

Anyone can help me?

**Broadcast Source**

```
public class ReceptorLlamadas extends BroadcastReceiver {

    @Override

    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {

          // Sacamos información del intent

          String estado = "Sin Estado", numero = "Sin Numero";

          Bundle extras = intent.getExtras();

          if(extras != null) {

                estado = "Sin Estado 1";
                numero = "Sin Numero 1"; 
                 estado = extras.getString(TelephonyManager.EXTRA_STATE);
                 numero = extras.getString( TelephonyManager.EXTRA_INCOMING_NUMBER);
                 if(estado.equals(TelephonyManager.EXTRA_STATE_RINGING)) {

                        numero = extras.getString( TelephonyManager.EXTRA_INCOMING_NUMBER);
                        Log.d("ReceptorAnuncio", "Weje1");
                        Intent i = new Intent(context, MainActivity.class);
                        i.putExtra("NUMERO", numero);
                        i.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);  
                        context.startActivity(i);
                        Log.d("ReceptorAnuncio", "Weje2"); 
                 }

                 Toast toast2 = Toast.makeText(context, "llamada " + estado + " de " + numero,Toast.LENGTH_LONG)    ; 
                 toast2.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER|Gravity.CENTER,0,0);
                 toast2.show();
          }

          String info = estado + " "+ numero;

          Log.d("ReceptorAnuncio", info + " intent="+ intent);


    }


}
```

**Activity Source**

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    String num;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        Bundle extras = getIntent().getExtras();

        num = "---------";
        if (extras != null)
        {   
            num = extras.getString("NUMERO");
        }
        Log.d("ReceptorAnuncio", "Arranca Activity " + num);
        TextView tel = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textViewTelefono);
        tel.setText(num);
        Button close_button = (Button) findViewById(R.id.close_button);
        close_button.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                finish();
            }
        });
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);

        return true;

    }

    @Override
    public void onDestroy()
    {
        super.onDestroy();
        Log.d("ReceptorAnuncio", "Fin Activity " + num);

    }


}
```

MANIFEST

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="com.example.llamadarecibida"
android:versionCode="1"
android:versionName="1.0" >

    <uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="8" android:targetSdkVersion="17" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE"/>

    <application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
        <activity
        android:name="com.example.llamadarecibida.MainActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name" android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Dialog">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <receiver android:name="ReceptorLlamadas" >
            <intent-filter>

                <action android:name="android.intent.action.PHONE_STATE" />

            </intent-filter>

        </receiver>

    </application>

</manifest>
```

Comment: put your manifest file..

Comment: You should find your answer there http://stackoverflow.com/q/5427017/2238341

Comment: ok thnaks .I had not seen