# Present pop-up notifications while on call - Android

Tags: android, kotlin, notifications, popup, android-notifications

My question is kinda simple, but for some reason I wasn't able to find any proper answer in the documentation.

Is it possible to present a pop-up notification (push/local) while on call?

I referred to [this article](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5427017/android-presenting-a-notification-during-a-call) and whilst its kinda similar (saying he wasn't able to present the notification as a pop-up) the solutions there are not relevant to my case.

Worth mentioning the code is filled with all the necessary configurations to make the notification appear as a POP UP (i.e channel importance MAX, and priority MAX as well, for old devices)

Also, I tried to understand if its happening in different apps, and saw that even Whatsapp doesn't pop up the notification while on call.

Lastly, what is the alternative? Will it work with SMS? Maybe since its internal and a part of the system, the system will allow its notification to pop up?

Notification channel setup code(part of it):

```
val notificationChannel = NotificationChannel(notificationChannelID, "com.qyooz.notification1", NotificationManager.IMPORTANCE_MAX)
```

Notification setup:

```
        val estimated_time_notification = NotificationCompat.Builder(applicationContext, notificationChannelID)
            .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_notification)
            .setLargeIcon(bitMapIconEstimated)
            .setContentTitle("Estimated waiting time:")
            .setContentText("$totalWaitingTime")
            .setAutoCancel(true)
            .setChannelId(notificationChannelID)
            .setStyle(NotificationCompat.DecoratedCustomViewStyle())
            .setContentIntent(pendingIntent)
            .setGroup(GROUP_KEY)
            .setPriority(NotificationCompat.PRIORITY_MAX).build()
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You should also use `setFullScreenIntent()` for your notification (and add new permission `<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.USE_FULL_SCREEN_INTENT" />`) and `setCategory(Notification.CATEGORY_CALL)`.

Comment: Hi, thanks for trying to help. I have tried this and it didn't work. It just opens the app on top of the call, while I only want it to appear as normal pop up notification, and not covering the whole screen. Do you have any suggestions?